# Circuit/schematic review ATMEGA328P

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, pcb-design, schematics, pcb-fabrication

Could someone suggest a place where I could request people to look over my schematic/board design?

If this is the place, here it is: https://easyeda.com/be.mihai22/project-hawk

EDIT:

As I see people started looking at this, here's what my thing looks like:
[image]
[image]
[image]

The three diagrams will form a circuit that will fly a quadcopter. It contains 3 ICs (accelerometer/barometer/magnetometer/gyro) for drone stability, one IC for detecting current/voltage.

What is more, it has an interface for raspberry pi zero which will generate +  communicate a PPM signal (like a receiver) from 4G/Wifi.

I will also keep a list of things that you have suggested for change in this header:

Problems:
 1. Sourcing 12V directly into ATMEGA328P Many thanks to Ron Beyer

Comment: Not sure this is the place, but why are you running 12V directly into an ATMega328?

Comment: Upload a screengrab or image here so we don't have to follow a link. It might help to explain what the circuit does and what your concerns are.

Comment: Try the EEVBlog forum: https://www.eevblog.com/forum/ Indeed feeding 12 V directly into an ATMega328 is a recipe for disaster. The ATMega will be destroyed on the spot!

Comment: Great spot. I have updated the question and I will keep a list of problems encountered and by whom.

Comment: One of the ICSP pins must be connected to the reset pin directly, not through a capacitor

Comment: @Simson, could you suggest how the capacitor will influence the ICSP? I am thinking if a separate route would be needed. If you look in the MICRO diagram, I have tried to place pins so that I can connect a FTDI on one side and be able to connect to the other side with ICSP. Could you suggest why DTR (Reset + capacitor) would not be suited? (P.S: I noted that arduino will not use a capacitor on the reset)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll add it as an answer, since the comments are getting big...

- You should not supply 12V to the ATMega328. 3V3 would be a better choice here so you don't have to use level-shifting on the I<sup>2</sup>C lines.
- You are pulling up the reset to 12V, change this to 3V3 as well.
- You have 2 different grounds defined. This can cause problems and you should probably decide to name them the same or connect them with a 0R resistor.
- No reverse voltage protection on the voltage inputs
- VDDA (analog reference voltage) should be filtered, you can use a ferrite bead for this
- The LED's are using 10K resistors, which may be too high for the 3V3 voltage, they will probably be so dim you can't see them.
- The Inhibit pin on the LDO should be connected directly to 5V.
- The input capacitor on the LDO should be between 5V and ground, not Inhibit.
- 10K pull-ups for the I<sup>2</sup>C lines are probably too big. You should be using something in the 2.2K-4.7K range.
- If you run the ATMega and the current monitor chips on 3V3 instead of 5V, you can eliminate the I<sup>2</sup>C level-shifting.
- The HMC5883L should have a 4.7uF *polarized* capacitor on the C1 line.
- VDD on the HMC5883L should have a capacitor placed close to the power pins.

Also, check the availability of some of your parts. The CSTCE16M0V53 looks to be obsolete/End-of-life.

Comment: This is great feedback mate.

Comment: I started implementing and I have some questions. a) Why polarized capacitor for C1? b) Can you confirm that my level shifter is 2N7002DW? ( I copied this part at my best knowledge). Also, how should I submit my result for more feedback? I think reposting this is not really advised on stackexchange. Again, thank you so much for all the feedback. It's invaluable.

Comment: Also, what properties should the ferrite bead have and why filtering VDD is necessary?

Comment: The polarized capacitor is required by the datasheet, the device may use it for some internal circuitry so it's best to use the kind/size it recommends. I honestly believe you should get rid of the level shifter and run everything at 3.3V. The ferrite bead is required for analog circuitry inside the chip to run correctly with a good reference. You will have a noisy voltage source (with motors) so you want to filter the analog side. You might want to ask on [meta](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/) about how to repost.

Comment: Eliminated the level shifter. Running everything on 3V3 now. It was a great idea. Also realized my current sensor was mislabeled. My intention was to use that with the raspi bus (so I will have a separate bus). Here it is. https://easyeda.com/be.mihai22/project-hawk

Comment: Also, could you clarify the feedback about ferrite bead? Is it referring to VDDA on BMP085? I now replaced this with BMP180 which only has VDDIO. Thanks!